# ¿Como pasar varios parametros a una query para poder hacer un select complejo?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, entity-framework, select

Puedo pasar a mi select el string correcto usando simplemente los parámetros de entrada de la función sin usar setParameter, pero lo veo problemático desde el punto de vista de la seguridad. Pasando solo el email no hay problema. He intentando varias combinaciones para pasarle dos valores para los dos ? sin buenos resultados.

```
String sql = "select U.id from bancoPepito.usuario U where "
                    + "U.email like ? and U.password like ?";
            try {
                Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
                query.setParameter(1,email);
                query.setParameter(2,password)
```

Evidentemente no doy con la forma de hacer setParameter bien. Un empujón sería de ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una opción sería usar la clase PreparedStatement, en vez de NativeQuery, y usar el método:

```
query.setString(1,email)` y `query.setString(2,password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Me funciono. Pero no entiendo porque razón no me funcionaba al principio. Hice otro ejemplo que necesita usar o hacer una query con dos campos y me va. 
Lo pongo aquí por si es de algún interés. Muchas gracias.

```
public PuntuadasRespuestas puedeVotarUsuarioLaRespuesta (Long idUsuario, Long idRespuesta) {
                //return puntuadasRespuestaRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
                PuntuadasRespuestas modelo = null;

                String sql = "select * from sanihelp.puntuadas where "
                        + "respuesta_puntuada = ? and puntuada_by_id = ?";

                try {
                    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);

                    query.setParameter(1, idRespuesta );
                    query.setParameter(2, idUsuario );
                    System.out.println(sql);

                    for (Object o : query.getResultList()) {
                        Object[] objeto = (Object[]) o;
                        modelo = new PuntuadasRespuestas();
                        modelo.setId(((BigInteger) objeto[0]).longValue());     
                        modelo.setRespuestaPuntuada(((BigInteger) objeto[1]).longValue());  
                        modelo.setActiva(Boolean.getBoolean(String.valueOf(objeto[2])));
                        modelo.setAux(String.valueOf(objeto[3]));
                        modelo.setCreateAt((java.util.Date)objeto[4]);
                        modelo.setPuntuadaById(((BigInteger) objeto[5]).longValue());   

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR::: excepcion lanzada" + e);
                }
                return modelo;
            }
```